# Dynamically Generating Select OptGroup Options in PHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp, html-select, optgroup

i have an array as follows and i want to build a nested options of Select DropDown

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'ProductCategory' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'name' => 'Mud',
            'parent_id' => '0'
        ),
        'children' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'ProductCategory' => array(
                    'id' => '6',
                    'name' => 'Sand',
                    'parent_id' => '5'
                ),
                'children' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'ProductCategory' => array(
                            'id' => '7',
                            'name' => 'Soil',
                            'parent_id' => '6'
                        ),
                        'children' => array()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'ProductCategory' => array(
            'id' => '8',
            'name' => 'House',
            'parent_id' => '0'
        ),
        'children' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'ProductCategory' => array(
                    'id' => '9',
                    'name' => 'Door',
                    'parent_id' => '8'
                ),
                'children' => array(
                    (int) 0 => array(
                        'ProductCategory' => array(
                            'id' => '11',
                            'name' => 'Latch',
                            'parent_id' => '9'
                        ),
                        'children' => array()
                    ),
                    (int) 1 => array(
                        'ProductCategory' => array(
                            'id' => '12',
                            'name' => 'Glass',
                            'parent_id' => '9'
                        ),
                        'children' => array(
                            (int) 0 => array(
                                'ProductCategory' => array(
                                    'id' => '13',
                                    'name' => 'Semi ',
                                    'parent_id' => '12'
                                ),
                                'children' => array()
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'ProductCategory' => array(
                    'id' => '10',
                    'name' => 'Window',
                    'parent_id' => '8'
                ),
                'children' => array()
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Am looking for an Efficient way to loop through and create HTML Code as follows. I am not sure how many level it will have. so i need a proof looping.

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Level One">
     <option> A.1 </option>
     <optgroup label="Level Two">
      <option> A.B.1 </option>
     </optgroup>
     <option> A.2 </option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Example of Nested Look via Dropdown

```
News
--Sport
----Sky
----Football
------Football-1
--War
----War1
--tech
Article
--tech
----tech2
------tech3
--php
--linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to use multilevel deep in `select` tag (HTML restrictions).

But You can build simple dropdown without `optgroup` using [`HtmlHelper::nestedList();`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3anestedList)

Answer (score 1):

From CI Form Helper:

[Click here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

```
function form_dropdown($name = '', $options = array(), $selected = array(), $extra = ''){
    if ( ! is_array($selected))
    {
        $selected = array($selected);
    }

    // If no selected state was submitted we will attempt to set it automatically
    if (count($selected) === 0)
    {
        // If the form name appears in the $_POST array we have a winner!
        if (isset($_POST[$name]))
        {
            $selected = array($_POST[$name]);
        }
    }

    if ($extra != '') $extra = ' '.$extra;

    $multiple = (count($selected) > 1 && strpos($extra, 'multiple') === FALSE) ? ' multiple="multiple"' : '';

    $form = '<select name="'.$name.'"'.$extra.$multiple.">\n";

    foreach ($options as $key => $val)
    {
        $key = (string) $key;

        if (is_array($val) && ! empty($val))
        {
            $form .= '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">'."\n";

            foreach ($val as $optgroup_key => $optgroup_val)
            {
                $sel = (in_array($optgroup_key, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

                $form .= '<option value="'.$optgroup_key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $optgroup_val."</option>\n";
            }

            $form .= '</optgroup>'."\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $sel = (in_array($key, $selected)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

            $form .= '<option value="'.$key.'"'.$sel.'>'.(string) $val."</option>\n";
        }
    }

    $form .= '</select>';

    return $form;
}
```

Example:

```
<?php
$options = Array(
    "value1" => "label1",
    "value3" => "label2",
    "value3" => "label3"
);
echo form_dropdown("my_field_name",$options,"value2","class='the_class_of_my_obj'");
?>
```

Example 2:

```
<?php
$options = Array(
    Array(
        "value1.1" => "label 1.1",
        "value1.2" => "label 1.2"
    ),
    "value3" => "label2",
    "value3" => "label3"
);
echo form_dropdown("my_field_name",$options,"value2","class='the_class_of_my_obj'");
?>
```

Comment: can this create multilevel?

Comment: Yes... I will put an example

Comment: doesnt his only generate only 2 levels. unfortunately i use cakephp and not CI :(

Comment: `select` tag ***cannot*** more then 2 levels, read my answer.

Comment: But you dont have to use the CI to use this function, just paste it in your code and enjoy it!